# Is the CMake generated project ony for build?

Tags: cmake

I am a bit confused about CMake workload, so in a project with my sources I add a CMakeLists.txt, and in a build dir i just create the CMake build project which only will be used to build, so that i only edit in the location where originally are my sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is called "out of source builds".

It has multiple advantages over the old style of having a "build" subdirectory or putting the object files directly next to your source and header files.

Most obvious advantage is that you can guarantee that everything is rebuild when you delete the build directory. In our build automatisation file we make the source tree readonly to guarantee a clean build without accidental checkins of build fragments.